# Not able to pass data from HTTP post request to the javascript(expressjs) controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am using react at the frontend and expressjs at the backend. Creating a simple post request and passing json data to the back end via the front end. THe request consist of body{title:"some title", content:"some content"}. In the back end if I console.log(req.body), I am getting an empty object. Also If i use postman it works correctly.
Front end Code :

```
fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: postData.title,
        content: postData.content
      })
    })
```

BackEnd code:

```
const title = req.body.title;
  const content = req.body.content;
  console.log(req);
  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'created nicely',
    post: {
      _id: '78',
      title: title,
      content: content,
      creator: { name: 'mera naam' },
      createdAt: new Date()
    }
  });
```

Comment: `method` has value in "method: method"? Any error in browser console or network tools? Have you enabled cors?

Answer (score 3):

The `header` property should be [`headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

```
fetch(url, {
  method: method,
  headers: {
  //  ^^^
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title: postData.title,
    content: postData.content,
  }),
})
```

Because the `Content-Type` header isn't being sent due to the misspelling, `body-parser` or `express.json()` (whichever you're using) doesn't parse the request body.